# Setting Android studio sdk location that is hidden on Mac

Tags: android, macos, sdk

I maintain my Android sdk through brew which means it can be found in "/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/22.6"

But I can't work out how to set this location in Android Studio, I go to the right place in settings but the field only lets you use a pop up finder window which means I can't navigate to the directory where my sdk is located. I tried showing all hidden files in Finder which works there but not in the pop up for Android Studio.

any ideas?

Comment: Command shift G from the window.  Although this is a Mac user trick, the question is on topic as it concerns a **development tool**

Comment: You could also try creating a symlink to the actual location from some more easily browsable one, perhaps in your home directory.

Comment: Creating the symlink seems to work. Do the following: 
`cd /Applications/Android Studio.app` then remove (or rename) the sdk directory within and then `ln -s /usr/local/opt/android-sdk sdk`